# Alternative to manipulating top for absolute scrolling or high performance height getter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-position

After profiling my code, I have isolated the bottleneck to getting the height of an element.

I am currently scrolling/paginating database results of entire tables by setting rows to `position: absolute`, accumulating their `heights`, and applying that accumulation to the subsequent rows' `top`s.

Everything works imperceptibly fast, but getting the height, be it by `$.height()` or even `offsetHeight`, introduces a delay of 5ms per row which accumulates to a perceptible 75ms per "page" of 15 rows.

Is there a higher performance alternative to absolute scrolling, or is there a higher performance way to get an element's height?

How can my intent be implemented?

Comment: can you share jsfiddle?

Comment: @monkeyinsight Thank you for looking!  It's a little argh-long, so please give me a little time to compress it and reproduce it without a database.  Thank you so much in advance!